# "Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence error" error while checking Persian characters with JQuery RegExp

Tags: jquery, regex, persian

I want to check input characters with RegExp in JQuery. Characters should be Persian, space or half-space.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}| |\x{200C}])+$/);
if(!pattern.test(name)){
    console.log('error');
}
```

I check this code in [online regex test](https://regex101.com)

and it works well! However, when I write it in my code, it doesn't work correctly and a syntax error is displayed.
PHPStorm notifies me with this error:

```
Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works well!

Perhaps, it works well with PCRE, but not with JavaScript. Be careful with the regex flavors you choose on the left at regex101.com.

You need to use `\u` notation with a literal:

```
var pattern = /^[\u0600-\u06FF\u200C ]+$/;
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW7qJ0/1)

Also, note that you do not need to set a capturing group around a character class and then apply a quantifier: you will lose in performance. You can refer to the whole match using a `$&` backreference. And `|` symbols in a character class are treated as a literal `|` symbol, not alternation, so I suppose we'd better remove it.

Comment: In case you need to match all Unicode spaces, they are listed [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html).

Comment: I just changed \x to \u and I removed brackets:
/^([\u0600-\u06FF| |\u200C])+$/
 It works fine now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function testreg(name){
var pattern = new RegExp("^([\\u0600-\\u06FF\\u200C ])+$");
if(!pattern.test(name)){
    alert('error');
  }
  else{alert('ok');}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testreg('1394/04/29')">testreg</button>
```

Comment: or use for  persian character : var SHAMSI_REGEXP = /^1[34][0-9][0-9]\/((0[1-6]\/((3[0-1])|([1-2][0-9])|(0[1-9])))|((1[0-2]|(0[7-9]))\/(30|([1-2][0-9])|(0[1-9]))))$/gi;

Comment: ^Your comment doesn't make any sense. Your example is also rather irrelevant.

Comment: why? He can change RegExp